# Does ASP.NET Core MVC support offline mode for viewing data and submitting data

Tags: bootstrap-4, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are building a web application which uses the following technologies:-

1. ASP.NET Core MVC
2. SQL Server
3. Entity Framework core
4. Bootstrap
5. IIS

now can we run our web application in offline mode, for those screens as an example:-

1. We have a form where users enter some data >> upload images >> click on submit.
2. We have a view where the user can view all the projects assigned to him, and clicking on a project will open the project details

So can we force our application to work in offline mode for the above 2 screens, using web browsers on PC and also on web browsers on mobile phones (mainly IOS + Android)? for example when a user fill out the form >> and click on submit while there is no connection >> to force the form to auto submit behind the scenes when the connection is back?

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET is only concerned with server-side HTTP request-processing. It is not a client-side platform or framework. "Offline mode" is a client-side thing and it is your responsibility as a front-end developer to build the code for that depending on your end application.

Answer (score 1):

> Now can we run our web application in offline mode,

Yes, but you may as well have just told us what you ate your breakfast this morning instead of your server-side stack because building an "offline-mode" for your web-application *has absolutely nothing to do with your server-side platform* and everything to do with client-side (i.e. JavaScript) code for [Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline) and [other parts of a typical PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/tools-for-pwa-developers).

ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core, *etc* <sub>(except for Blazor... that's an entirely different story)</sub> is only concerned with generating HTTP responses for incoming HTTP requests, and for running code in the server.

You will need to be careful with your Razor `.cshtml` views and any JavaScript that's generated for you by parts of ASP.NET MVC/ASP.NET Core's tooling and infrastructure - those those in-box scripts are more like *script islands* instead of being the basis of your application (as is the case with Angular, and certain React/Vue project templates), which can be worked-around by your Service Worker in order to make offline-mode work more smoothly.

Comment: i did not have my breakfast today, that why i did not mention it :) ... so which client side technology you adivce to use to support offline mode? does HTML-5 and JavaScript support Offline? or i need to use specific client side tools?Thanks

Comment: The _only_ thing that matters for offline-mode today (in 2022) is [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which is part of the DOM/standard in-browser JavaScript. You don't "need" any "technology" nor any specific tooling (i.e. you can use Notepad). Previously (back in 2011-2012) you needed an _offline manifest_ but not anymore (any guides that talk about needing a manifest for offline-mode are wrong and outdated (except for PWAs: PWAs still need manifests).